# activex in actionscript

Tags: javascript, actionscript, activex, mxml

Is it possible to run an activex control in a MXML file using actionscript? Here's an equivalent of what I would like to do in Javascript

```
function getUserName(){
var s = new ActiveXObject("wscript.network");
return s.username;
}
```

-- Just a simple "hello world" example would be great. I can take it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in javascript and then use `ExternalInterface` to communicate between your flash/flex app and your javascript functions.

You can check documentation here : http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=passingarguments_4.html

Comment: Thanks alot. I tried doing this before but for some reason it wasnt working. Took a step back and tried it again clean and it worked.